# DEM from LiDAR using cloud compare

Tags: dem, lidar, cloudcompare

I am working on overseeing a comprehensive flood analysis project in Bardonecchia, Turin, Italy, post the August 2023 flood event.
I have been handed over the LiDAR file .las in which flood occurs.
I want to extract DEM out of it to use in QGIS to make computational mesh to further use in Basement for analysis.

The steps which I am following is:

1. Loading the .las file in the cloud compare
2. Applying SOR and noise filter
3. Setting the scalar field to coordinate Z because I do not have classification option there.
4. Rasterizing, putting step as 1, active layer as cell height values, direction Z, cell height average, std. dev. layer is already set by default to return number and ticking the project SF(s) to average value, fill with interpolate , empty cell value as 0.
5. When I got my raster in QGIS, it is not showing elevation profile or any number when I am choosing the find arrow on any point on the raster in QGIS.

Can someone guide me about this?

Comment: Can you provide a subset of the data to test on? Can you specify exactly which steps/functions you used and the parameters you used (such as for the SOR and noise filter)?

Comment: I can provide you the subset if you can provide me email of yours because i think its not possible to upload here?

Comment: can you put it on google drive and paste the link here? That way other people can access it and try to find you a solution too.

Comment: this is the link to the .las file to the dropbox https://www.dropbox.com/t/dgZxsWmqzOFQbWZR (55GB).

 it is really big file, you can open it with cloud compare. I want dem out of it to use in qgis to make computational mesh.

Comment: and for sor and noise i use default settings

Comment: I'm not downloading a file that is 55Gb. Clip the area to something smaller so it is easier to work with.